# I am trying to do a program that picks a vowel from the user input

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{    
    char *v= "a";
    char *o='e';
    char * w='i';
    char  *e='o';
    char  *l='u'; 
    char *u[1];

    printf  ("please enter your character\n");
    scanf  ("%c",& u); 

    if  (u == v){
        puts("the character is it a vowel\n");
    }
    if  (u == o) {
        puts("the character is it a vowel\n"); 
    }  
    else 
        puts("the character is  a constant\n");      
    system("PAUSE");    
    return 0;
}
```

i need help in getting the right answer in finding a vowel from the user input.

Comment: "I need help...." yes, we all need help some times.  But you've got to work for it. What is your program producing? What are you expecting it to produce? You can't just post some code then beg us to debug it for you.

Comment: "I need help" is not a question. You need to explain how what you've tried does not match what you want, and give your thoughts on what the problem might be.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, shame on you for ignoring all of the compiler warnings you certainly received. They are there to help prevent you from doing "stupid things."

And why all this nonsense? This is the first of the "stupid things" the compiler is trying to tell you about.

```
char *v= "a";
char *o='e';     // invalid - Initializing a pointer to a constant 'e' (101).
char * w='i';    // invalid 
char  *e='o';    // invalid
char  *l='u';    // invalid
```

Are you familiar with how pointers work?  If not, I suggest you [do some reading](http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm) and understand them.

The first line makes sense - you're making a string and pointing `char* v` to that string.

But there's really no point in using pointer for those characters - or even variables at all. Just compare them directly:

```
char my_character;
if (my_character == 'a') {
  // do something
}
```

---

And as for reading the character, again, you're using pointers when it doesn't make sense:

```
char *u[1];   // why?
```

Instead, just define a single `char` variable. Now, go look at the documentation for `scanf`. Giving it a format string of `"%c"` means, "I want to read just one character".  Then, you need to tell where `scanf` to put it. You do this by passing it the *"address of"* the variable you want to store it in.  You do this with (unsurprisingly!) the *address of* operator `&`.

```
char input_character;
scanf("%c", &input_character);
```

Armed with this information, you should be able to complete your work.  Next, I suggest you look into the [switch statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement).

Finally, you *must* use consistent formatting (indentation, spacing) and use meaningful variable names, if you have any desire of ever being taken seriously as a programmer.  Spelling out "vowel" for your pointless variables may be "cute" but it's total nonsense.

Most importantly, you should *never* write a single line of code, unless you understand exactly what it does. If you do this, then do not go asking anyone for help (especially not StackOverflow). If you can't explain what your code is doing (or at least what you think it's supposed to do), then you don't deserve for your program to work.